# How to export to xls file is working on meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an objects. When click a button that objects is stored in a variable. At that same click function I need to export that objects to xls(excel) file in Meteor. Any help?

```
   html page
  <button class="export-data btn btn-success" type="submit" >Export Data</button>

 JavaScript file, client side
Template.ExportActivationCodes.events({
"click .export-data": function (event, template) {
    var advertiserdatas = template.find("#exportId").value;
    var nameFile = 'fileDownloaded.csv';
    Meteor.call('download',advertiserdatas, function(err, fileContent)    {
        if (fileContent) {
            var blob = new Blob([fileContent], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
            saveAs(blob, nameFile);
        }
    });
   }
  });


 Meteor methods server side

 download: function(advertiserdatas) {
    var collection = ActivationCodes.find({advertiserId:parseInt(advertiserdatas)}).fetch();
    var heading = true; // Optional, defaults to true
    var delimiter = ";" // Optional, defaults to ",";

    return exportcsv.exportToCSV(collection, heading, delimiter);
}
```

Comment: What file? I have working excel-export in my projects.

Any help? Yes, try google: meteor excel export.

Comment: I think you should use PapaParse http://papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv and there is a good code help here https://github.com/rafaelquintanilha/meteor-json-to-csv/blob/master/client/exporter.js
Have fun coding :)